# R Shiny reactivePoll inside observeEvent doesnt execute valueFunc

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I want to have a `valueFun` executed when a button is clicked, so that a plot arises...however only `checkFunc` is executed (the time is being printed in the console....but `data_poll` is not being updated via `valueFunc` of `generate_data` function. Why?

```
library(shiny)

# Function to generate random data
generate_data <- function() {
  data <- data.frame(
    x = rnorm(10),
    y = rnorm(10)
  )
  return(data)
}

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("ReactivePoll Example"),
  mainPanel(
    actionButton("btn", "Click Me!"),
    uiOutput('uioutput')
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data_poll <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  # Observing the button click event
  observeEvent(input$btn, {
    # Display a message when the button is clicked
    output$eventText <- renderText({
      "Button Clicked!"
    })
    
    # Function to poll for updated data every 10 seconds
    data_poll <- reactivePoll(
      intervalMillis = 10000,
      session = session,
      checkFunc = function() {
        # Return a timestamp to trigger polling
        Sys.time()
        print(Sys.time())
      },
      valueFunc = function() {
        # Generate new data
        generate_data()
      }
    )
  })
  
  output$uioutput = renderUI({
    if (!is.null(data_poll()) && nrow(data_poll()) > 0) {
      plotOutput("scatterPlot")
    }
  })
  
  # Render the scatter plot
  output$scatterPlot <- renderPlot({
    data <- data_poll()
    plot(data$x, data$y, main = "Scatter Plot", xlab = "X", ylab = "Y")
  })
  
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

ReactivePoll code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("ReactivePoll Example"),
  mainPanel(
    actionButton("btn", "Click Me!"),
    uiOutput('uioutput'),
    textOutput("eventText")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data_poll <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  ready <- reactiveVal(FALSE)
  
  # Display a message when the button is clicked
  observeEvent(input$btn, {
    
    ready(TRUE)
    
  })
  
  data_poll <- reactivePoll(
    intervalMillis = 10000,
    session = session,
    checkFunc = function() {
      # Return a timestamp to trigger polling
      
      Sys.Date()
      
      print(Sys.Date())
    },
    valueFunc = function() {
      # Generate new data
      req(ready())
      generate_data()
    }
  )
  
  output$uioutput = renderUI({
    req(data_poll(), ready())
    plotOutput("scatterPlot")
  })
  
  # Render the scatter plot
  output$scatterPlot <- renderPlot({
    req(ready())
    data <- data_poll()
    plot(data$x, data$y, main = "Scatter Plot", xlab = "X", ylab = "Y")
  })
  
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I've never seen an instance where nesting reactives (and/or observers) made any sense, nor added any value of functionality that could not be done more simply via all "top-level" (within `server`) reactive/observe blocks.

Comment: You never define `eventText`, what are you expecting `output$eventText` to be doing?

Comment: @r2evans has nailed one important issue [nesting observers/reactives] with your code.  Another is that the object retuned by `generate_data` is not reactive, so an update to your `renderPlot` is (probably) never triggered.

Comment: @Limey, I don't think `generate_data` is intended to be reactive, it is just a function called within a reactive block.

Comment: H.berg, it's not clear to me what the button is supposed to be doing. Is it that the plot should not auto-update until the user clicks the button? That is, the button _starts_ the `reactivePoll` process?

Comment: Hi thank you so much! I understand that my workflow is a bit vague, but I added an explanation why i did it like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never seen an instance where nested `reactive`/`observe` blocks added any value, more often nesting them causes problems with flow.

1. Remove the nesting.
2. Add `input$btn` to the `output$eventText`.
3. Add `textOutput("eventText")`, likely just an oversight in your example.
4. Changed from `reactivePoll` to `invalidateLater(10000)` within a `reactive(..)`.

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("ReactivePoll Example"),
  mainPanel(
    actionButton("btn", "Click Me!"),
    uiOutput('uioutput'),
    textOutput("eventText")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data_poll <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  ready <- reactiveVal(FALSE)
  
  # Display a message when the button is clicked
  output$eventText <- renderText({
    req(input$btn)
    ready(TRUE)
    "Button Clicked!"
  })
  
  data_poll <- reactive({
    req(ready())
    print(Sys.time())
    invalidateLater(10000, session)
    generate_data()
  })
  
  output$uioutput = renderUI({
    req(data_poll(), ready())
    plotOutput("scatterPlot")
  })
  
  # Render the scatter plot
  output$scatterPlot <- renderPlot({
    req(ready())
    data <- data_poll()
    plot(data$x, data$y, main = "Scatter Plot", xlab = "X", ylab = "Y")
  })
  
}
```

Edited so that the 10-second data generation doesn't start until the button is pressed.

If you need it, the "true" value of `ready()` can be toggled, which means you can choose to "stop/pause" the every-10-second poll.

Comment: Thx!, however I would like to load/generate the data after clicking the button. Currently it loads/generates immediately once the app is start up

Comment: I literally thought yesterdy evening about using req()..works nice! I also want to try it out with reactivePoll....to my reasoning req( ) should be added to checkFunc, however the app wont start than. It does work when I add req( ) to valueFunc...but why not to checkFunc? I have added some new code to the question

Comment: That's a good question; I don't use that function so I haven't run into that nuance. My reasoning _against_ using it is that it will always fire, even before the user pushes the button, and then you can "never" turn it off (not technically true, but not _easily_). Where I have need for user-initiated repetitive tasks, I prefer to be able to disable it too, where I often have a checkbox to indicate "repeat every so-many-seconds", so I use the method I have above. (There are perhaps some more safeguards to, I haven't filled it out enough for the toggling.)

Comment: The reason why I am curious in reactivePoll cause i have a workflow where data is fetched via an API call to a database. And I want the API calls to set to a minimum so thereby I would like to avoid using invalidateLater that always calls the APi to update the data

Comment: My code is doing what you said: it does nothing until the user presses a button, then it calls every 10 seconds. If you look at `shiny::reactivePoll`, it is using `invalidateLater` internally, so there's nothing fancy or new.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256451/discussion-between-h-berg-and-r2evans).